# FCNTL File IO errors using FFmpeg on iOS

Tags: ios, c, ffmpeg

I have an application that leverages FFmpeg libraries to play video (modeled after FFplay). It works on every platform except iOS, where I experience a strange file IO issue that I cannot figure out.

I am able to stream two videos successfully, but on the third stream attempt the calls to `av_read_frame()` fail and the AVIOContext shows error `9`, `E_BADF`. To investigate, I added some logging messages to try to see where the error originated and I found that the error was coming from the `read()` call inside the `file_read()` function in libavformat/file.c.

I then looked into how the video files were being opened and I found that on the third run, the `open()` call (inside `avpriv_open()` in libavutil/file_open.c) was returning `0` as the file descriptor, whereas the first two were returning more normal positive values. After a few successful attempts to read from `0`, the read calls proceeded to fail indefinitely with `E_BADF`.

The `0` file descriptor is usually reserved for `stdin`, and I am confident my application is not closing `stdin` at any point. Having `open()` return `0` as the file descriptor isn't inherently wrong, but in this case it eventually results in a read failure every time. I am able to work around this by artificially using up `0` in the table by opening something but not operating on it, and then restarting the open process to get back to a positive value. When I do this, my videos are able to play again. My only theory to explain this behaviour is that something somewhere is repeatedly closing the `0` file descriptor underneath my feet, which causes the read attempts to start failing.

I can't say for sure yet if this is a problem in FFmpeg or possibly the operating system, but I am unable to reproduce this issue in a simple program that doesn't use FFmpeg, nor does it occur on any other platform as I mentioned above. I have also tried many different versions of the FFmpeg source running on iOS versions 9 and 10 and they all demonstrate the issue. I realize iOS is not a high runner platform for FFmpeg use, but I am wondering if anyone has attempted to build and use FFmpeg for iOS and recognizes any of these issues. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.